# Combining functions from two separate controllers into one ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and nodeJS and am working on a project.  As it stands there exists two different controllers let's say "`controllerA`" and "`controllerB`" that have "`functionA`" and "`functionB`" being triggered by ng-click events on "`buttonA`" and "`buttonB`".

If I want to trigger functionA and functionB from one "`buttonC`", how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Post what have you tried yet.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Just call controllers on two different divs

```
<div ng-controller="controllerA">
 <div ng-controller = "controllerB">
  <input ng-click="functionA();functionB();"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

OR

call one controller controllerA in your routes for your view.
and call another controller controllerB in your view.

```
.state('app.example', {
  url: '/example',
  controller: 'controllerA',
  templateUrl: 'example.html',
})

<div ng-controller="controllerB">
  <input ng-click="functionA();functionB();"/>
</div>
```

By this, you can access two controllers